# Using Python to retrieve cookies from a web login page (uncompleted)

Tags: python, cookies, web, request, httpresponse

Hello all… I am using Python to try to simulate login my work email, web base.

Now a problem lies on the first page of login. I observe the login process through IE9’s F12 (Developer tool) and found there are in total 3 cookies generated.

However when I use below scripts to visit the first page of login, there are only 2 cookies found. How could this be? How can I have all the cookies retrieved?

(I’ve cleared all the cache, cookie history, and empty the fold of Temporary Internet Files before catching)

```
loginUrl = "http://www.company.com/"

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(loginUrl)

for index, cookie in enumerate(cj):
    print '[',index, ']',cookie
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the first two cokies was returned from server [read about this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: foo=10
Set-Cookie: bar=20; Expires=Fri, 30 Sep 2011 11:48:00 GMT
```

the third one was generated by javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
```

Comment: thanks, qwetty. is there a way to find out which javascript is doing the generation job? and is there a way to simulate the generation?

Comment: Looking into code :) Or use for this Python Selenium http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html, Has a method get_cookie
 http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=cookie#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get_cookie

Comment: thanks again, qwetty. I will look them into details.

Comment: I don't know if selenium fits Your needs, but it open "normal" webbrowser (firefox, chrome what ever its up to You) and then You have access to page through browser. I used this for testing

Comment: now I know Selenium is a way to physically open, work and close Internet browser, which is different with other 'back-end' methods. I can't work something else when it's running but seems it's a necessary way.